# Associate two data into an one with Javascript (first value come by json)

Tags: javascript, json

I need help to associate values into an one, like JOIN in mysql.

The first url send the parameter and receive it (GET BY UF (ITS COME FROM ANOTHER FILE)):

```
<option value="8080">ABDON BATISTA</option>
<option value="8081">ABELARDO LUZ</option>
<option value="8082">AGROLANDIA</option>
....
```

As you can see, each name has an value, in case of agrolandia the value is 8082.

I need get this value.

But my json retrieve it (the json use (cep/postal code) and get name of city and others parameters:

```
{
    "cidade":"São José",
    "bairro":"Campinas",
    "cep":"88101-000",
    "uf":"SC",
    "endereco":"Avenida Presidente Kennedy"
}
```

First thing that I need is to format field "cidade" to UPPERCASE; second is associate the value of the field "cidade" with the selected value in

IN SUME:

SELECT cidade WHERE cidade (come by json) = "cidade" (inside THIS CIDADE") so I receive the value.

```
My scripts:

var urlCep = 'site/getendereco?cep=';
$.getJSON(urlCep + $("[name=cep]").val(), function(d) {
    $("[name=cidade]").val(d.cidade);
    $("[name=uf]").val(d.uf);
    $("[name=endereco]").val(d.endereco);
    $("[name=bairro]").val(d.bairro);
});

$('[name=estado]').change(function(){
    $.get('/site/cidades_ajax/' + $(this).val())
})
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML for I shall implement a test?

Comment: Hello @Samuel, i got a progress... now i just need compare my string to the list in case..
my php code

echo "<option value='" . $cidade->id . "'>" . $cidade->nome . "</option>";

output:

<option value="8080">ABDON BATISTA</option>

so i formated my string (d.cidade output:SAO JOSE) to match in php result, so if its equall i get that value and insert on my select.

Comment: If you want to use javascript. I think that you what to do something like .NET LINQ. There are this javascript lib that work this way.

[http://linqjs.codeplex.com/][1]


  [1]: http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Comment: my friend told me to use :contains() Selector from jQuery.